# how does hibernate map its columns to DB

Tags: hibernate

I thought when I have a class that I add the @Entity to it and also map it to a table, then when on a get property I add the @Column attribute and tell it what column of that table it should map it to... then I saw the @Transient annotation and it says if we add @Transient to a get, then Hibernate will Not save it to DB...so then I got confused: so does it mean default behaviour of Hibernate is to map every get to a similar named column in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every non static non transient property (field or method depending
>   on the access type) of an entity is considered persistent, unless you
>   annotate it as @Transient. Not having an annotation for your property
>   is equivalent to the appropriate @Basic annotation. The @Basic
>   annotation allows you to declare the fetching strategy for a property:

[@official hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity.

Depending on where you put the `@Id` annotation (on a field or on a getter), all fields or getters not marked with `@Transient` will automatically be made persistent, with a default column name.